# Calculate the volume of the solid

Tags: definite-integrals, volume

Which is generated from the common part of $$ y =x^2$$ and $$y^2=8x$$ as it rotates around $0y$. Limits of the integral should be from $0$ to $4$ right? Shouldn't the integral be $$π\int_0^4(x^2 - \sqrt{8x})^2dx$$

Comment: The intersection of the two curves is at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$

Comment: see my answer${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

### Scale misleading

---

### Answer

At $y$ distance from origin we take a thin vertical ring of thickness $dy$. Now volume of this ring is:
$$dV=\pi(x_o^2-x_i^2)dy$$
where $r_i$ and $r_o$ are inner and outer radii.
Now inner radii will be on blue curve such that:
$$8x_i=y^2$$
And the outer radii:
$$x_o^2=y\implies x_o=+\sqrt y$$
Note the "+" because we're for the time being taking the I<sup>st</sup> quadrant in consideration.
Now $$dV=\pi(y-y^4/64)dy$$
They intersect at $k=h^2,k^2=8h\implies h=2,k=4$
And:
$$V=\int_0^4\pi(y-y^4/64)dy=\frac{24\pi}5$$

Comment: That is not a plot of $y^2=8x$ :)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake with one function and forgot to include the $8$. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user3601507 Does that mean your'e going to accept this answer and upvote it?